# Why is angular velocity in the $z$-direction?

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics

My physics professor (at a T10 university) was unable to explain this. He mentioned something about a bivector, but fundamentally did not say why $w_{z} = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$, and that is what my question is. I would also like more intuition on why the angular velocity is in the $z$-direction. He said that the accurate representation of a plane is a bivector, but that is complex, so the next best thing is a vector perpendicular to the plane, which makes sense. What does not make sense is that $\theta(t)$ is a measurement in the $xy$-plane, yet the derivative $w_{z} = \frac{d\theta}{dt}$ is a magnitude in the $z$-direction.

Please do not tell me about the right hand rule unless you're going to explain why it works.
I have background in lower-division math courses only, single and multi variable calculus, linear algebra, and differential equations, so please direct your explanation at that. I am in the physics series for engineers and am not a physics major, but I am curious why this works.

My question is fundamentally why the magnitude of the vector we are using to characterize our plane, which rotation occurs about, is $d\theta/dt$. Should the derivative of $\theta$ not be tangent to it, rather than perpendicular to the plane in which $\theta$ occurs?

Comment: If we're being pedantic, $\theta$ is not "in the $xy$-plane," it is a scalar that measures something in the $xy$-plane, and similarly the derivative ${\rm d}\theta/
{\rm d}t$ is a scalar, not a vector, so it is not "in the $z$-direction." It makes sense to multiply the scalar quantity ${\rm d}\theta/{\rm d}t$ by $\hat{z}$ (or whatever you want to call the unit vector) to get a vector, though, and I can see a physicist omitting that as abuse of notation.

Comment: Why is it incorrect to say that the $z$-component of $w$ is $d\theta/dt$, notation-wise @runway44 ?

Comment: I didn't say it was incorrect to say the $z$-component of $w$ was $d\theta/dt$. I just said $d\theta/dt$, by itself, is a scalar. | To your professor's point that we can represent a bivector for a plane as the perpendicular vector, you say "which makes sense." Yet the very next sentence you say it doesn't make sense. I don't know how to answer you when you simultaneously say something makes sense and doesn't.

Comment: The bivector makes sense, but it doesn't make sense to me that $w_{z} = d\theta/dt$. That is my fundamental question. Why is the magnitude of the angular acceleration in the $z$-direction and characterized by a derivative of something occuring in the $xy$-plane? To be clear, I'm not asking why we characterize it by a vector in the $z$-direction, but rather, why the magnitude of that vector is $d\theta/dt$.

Comment: The phrase "angular velocity" means rate at which angle is changing, so of course we define the magnitude to be $d\theta/dt$ here.

Comment: Yes but why can we say that angular velocity is in the $z$-direction, should the derivative of $\theta$ not be tangent to it?

Comment: If you have a curve ${\bf r}(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0)$ tracing out a circle in the $xy$-plane, then sure its directional derivative is tangent to the circle at the point. But that's not what we're talking about. We're talking about a vector quantity (called "angular velocity") which is defined to point perpendicular to the plane of rotation and whose magnitude is defined to be the rate of rotation.

Comment: And that is my question: why is its magnitude defined to be the rate of rotation? How is that relevant? I see its perpendicular to tell us where the plane is, sure, but there is no actual velocity in that direction, is there? So why give it that magnitude? Is there no physical or mathematical meaning to this?

Comment: The direction is chosen perpendicular to the plane of rotation because vectors are easier than bivectors. You said you understood that.

Comment: The direction is chosen, yes, it can be a unit vector, but why is a magnitude chosen for it when there is no magnitude in that direction? Do you understand my question?

Comment: Because using a vector in a cross product is easier than teaching people bivectors used as linear transformations. The angular velocity vector is not *supposed* to represent rotation in the *direction* it's pointing, it's *supposed* to represent rotation in the *perpendicular* plane, as a mathematical way of getting around bivectors.

Comment: I see. Thank you @runway44 . Do you know what class would teach me bivectors? I'm planning to minor in Math -- take probability theory, linear algebra, analysis, differential geometry maybe.

Comment: Differential geometry, representation theory, multilinear algebra, tensor analysis - these are some subject keywords.

Comment: Thanks. So you're saying that since $|A x B|$ is the area between $A$ and $B$, this is why we can say that $w_{z} = d\theta/dt$ ?

Comment: I don't see how area is relevant. Imagine $R(t)$ is a rotation matrix around a fixed axis in 3D space which represents rotation after time $t$ at constant angular speed. Its derivative $R'(0)$, as a linear operator, will project onto the perpendicular plane, rotate by $90^\circ$, then scale proportional to the speed of rotation (compare with $e^{i\omega t}$ and the complex plane!). One can think of $R'(0)$ as the bivector $m(u\wedge v)$, where $\{u,v\}$ is an oriented orthonormal basis for the plane of rotation, and $m$ is the correct magnitude.

Comment: As a linear transformation, $x\mapsto R'(0)x$ is equivalent to taking the cross product with the angular velocity, $\omega\mapsto\omega\times x$. By the properties of the cross product, $\omega$ must be in the direction of the axis of rotation, and have magnitude proportional to the speed of rotation. This is my Lie theory explanation for angular velocity.

Comment: I don't understand this and I think it's because I don't have enough background. I'll try to ask my professor about your explanation, but I think it would just require a lot more coursework to get to the point where I can understand what you are saying. Thanks for trying. I have a better idea for why it fits together now.

Comment: “Velocity” means a vector. If you remember the cross product multiplies vectors by rotating the first over the last. The rotation of initial position vector over the final position vector results in angular velocity.

Answer (score 1):

Consider an object circulating the origin, with its position given by

$ \vec{r} = (\cos \theta  , \sin \theta , 0)  $

Then the velocity is by definition given by $\dfrac{d \vec{r}}{dt}$

$ \vec{v} = \dfrac{d \vec{r}}{dt} = (- \sin \theta , \cos \theta, 0 ) \dfrac{d \theta}{dt} $

Note that $\vec{v}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{r}$.  We need to relate the vector $\vec{v}$ and the vector $\vec{r}$.  This can be done if we define the angular velocity vector to be

$ \vec{\omega} = (0, 0, \dfrac{ d \theta }{dt} ) $

Then one can see that

$ \vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r} $

And this is the motivation the vector angular velocity is defined as such.